# Basic php program: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am new to Facebook app development. I created a sample app for learning.  the code is as follows . Basically i want to print the profile name of the user. It will be great if I can get explanation of this code especially for the Italicized section.

```
enter code here
<html> 
<body>
<h1> Inspirations </h1>
<div id = "quote">
<span id="facebook_stuff">
<div id = "profile_pic"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/1452321522/picture"      border="0" /> </div>
<?php
 require 'facebook.php' ;
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
 ‘appId’ => 'my app id',
 ‘secret’ => 'my app secret',
 'cookie' => 'true',

   ));

 $user = $facebook->api('/1452321522');

  ?>
      <div id="profile_name"> <?php echo $user['name'] ?> </div>
   </span>
    "Love is god"
   </div>
    </body>
     </html>
```

**I am getting the following output**

Inspirations

{image}

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/04/8471304/html/index.php:5) in /home/content/04/8471304/html/facebook.php on line 37

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/04/8471304/html/index.php:5) in /home/content/04/8471304/html/facebook.php on line 37

Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token signature. thrown in /home/content/04/8471304/html/base_facebook.php on line 970

Comment: Please search a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+headers+already+sent

Answer (score 1):

For the first two warnings, you're trying to send headers (cookies and cache limiter) after output has already started, try moving the php code to the top as so:

```
 <?php
 require 'facebook.php' ;
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
 ‘appId’ => 'my app id',
 ‘secret’ => 'my app secret',
 'cookie' => 'true',

   ));

 $user = $facebook->api('/1452321522');

  ?>
<html> 
<body>
<h1> Inspirations </h1>
<div id = "quote">
<span id="facebook_stuff">
<div id = "profile_pic"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/1452321522/picture"      border="0" /> </div>
<div id="profile_name"> <?php echo $user['name'] ?> </div>
</span>
   "Love is god"
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't say as far as the fatal error, although my hunch is that it is related to the first two warnings, or it is because you're passing dummy values for 'appId' and 'secret' (which are not encased in apostrophes proper and might generate an error themselves)

Comment: I tried but again gives the error "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token signature. thrown in /home/content/04/8471304/html/base_facebook.php on line 970"

Answer (score 0):

As said by bkconrad,the first two warnings is for, you are sending some header information after some information sent to the browser.

For this you can try as suggested by bkconrad or use [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_end_flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php)
functions.And for the fatal error, you must give your id and secret code created in your facebook.

I assume you've created facebook application, so login into facebook and go to [facebook aps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps). There you've listed applications created by you. copy and paste **App ID/API Key** and **App Secret** in your code. That's it.